# Matlab to Python transformation: "poissinv" function

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to transform a piece of demand simulation code from Matlab to Python. But I didn't find a corresponding function for the "poissinv" yet.

poissinv(rand, 3), supposed to be giving a Poisson distributed number with a randomly generated percentile.

I would be glad if anyone shares experience if you also come across such a problem before.

I am using Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Matlab:

```
poissinv(0.95,2)
ans =   5
```

in Python

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
poisson.ppf(0.95,2)
Out[3]: 5
```

The randomly specified percetile `rand` in your questions, you would need to specify separately of course (and respect that you get different results in Python and Matlab if the random number process is not identical. The functions of course get the same results given the same `rand` as demonstrated in my example).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concise answer.